# Get primary key name from model in entity framework 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, helper

My project is developped with EF5 and MVC4. I want to create a helper for a model and inside this helper, I need to get primary key name for the model.

Here is my Helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DialogForModel(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    object model = html.ViewData.Model;
    string primaryKeyName = GetPrimaryKeyNameForModel(model);
    ...
}
```

I discovered that inside the model there is a property **_entityWrapper**. Inside this property there is another **EntityKey** with **EntityKeyNames**.

These properties have my primary key name and value, but I dont know how I can access it.

How can I do that?!

Comment: https://michaelmairegger.wordpress.com/2013/03/30/find-primary-keys-from-entities-from-dbcontext/ - bit late but thisll do what you are after I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need that, but this could solve your problem.
Create BaseEntity class with key property inside:

```
public class BaseEntity 
{
   public int Key { get; set; }
}
```

Let you all Model classes inherit form this class:

```
public class SomeModelClass: BaseEntity 
{
    public string Prop{ get; set; }
}
```

In your helper cast your model to BaseEntity and get Key value.